# log/dump response body

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-security

Is there any way to log response body in Apache 2?

I need the exact content that will be sent to user browser.

I tried `mod_security` audit logging, but it won't log response body for all requests.

(I got confused really. It logs response body for requesting a simple PHP page in a directory, but it won't log response body for another file in another directory. It just log response and request header.)

**Update:** here is `mod_security` configuration in main configuration file (httpd.conf):

```
SecAuditEngine On
SecRuleEngine On
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecResponseBodyAccess On
SecAuditLogParts ABCDEFGHZ
SecAuditLog logs/sec.log
```

Comment: Did you see this? http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/07-logging.html Note the example configuration.